# Is it possible to pass entire WHERE condition in stored procedure in MySQL 5.x?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I just need pass WHERE condition, like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `productpricing2`(
   IN cond CHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE cond LIMIT 1;
END
```

and call it like:

```
CALL productpricing2("productName IS NOT NULL");
```

Where productName is column in table tbl_products

Thanks

Comment: Please read about SQL Injection attacks before you go down this route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible You can use [prepared-statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for it, and build whole query as a string, but it's not an elegant way to do things...

also notice that:

- Yours queries should take advantage of parametrized prepared-statements, in case of SQL-Injection
- Even parametrized prepared-statements, are not fully "secure", and You should avoid that kind of DB programming

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible (although as HLGEM points out it opens you for possibility of SQL injections).

THe way to do this, is to create dynamic SQL using prepared statement.